# "Zone already loaded" angular universal ssr

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular6, server-side-rendering

Currently i'm working in a angular project . I want to do serverside rendering for my project. So i use angular universal for acheving that. My browser module is builded sucessfully but when server build is running i'm facing this issue.

```
    > ngx-admin@2.3.0 serve:ssr /var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular
> node dist/server

/var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:59430
        throw new Error('Zone already loaded.');
        ^

Error: Zone already loaded.
    at /var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:59430:15
    at /var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:60042:3
    at FUNCTION (/var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:59408:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:59410:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:59292:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:59355:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:59292:30)
    at Object.defineProperty.value (/var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:59344:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:59347:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/testproject/testprojectAngular/dist/server.js:23:30)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ngx-admin@2.3.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/server`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ngx-admin@2.3.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sys9/.npm/_logs/2019-07-26T05_19_29_348Z-debug.log
```

I didnt know why this issue occus . Any help is appreciable . note: i'm not using firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you put a screenshot with your index file also check
and make sure your not loading the module twice in index html